# R: (SQL style) %LIKE% statement

Tags: sql, r, select, merge, data-manipulation

I am trying to figure out how to use a statement similar to %LIKE% in the R programming language. Using the following stackoverflow post: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right), I was able to figure out how to run basic merges in SQL. But for some reason, this does not work with the %LIKE% condition.

For instance, if I create the following data:

```
table_a <- data.frame (

"name" = c("John", "ALex", "ToM", "Kev", "Peter"),
"color" = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink")

)

name$table_a = as.factor(name$table_a)
    
table_b <- data.frame (

"name" = c("Johnathan", "Alexander", "Tomas", "Kevin", "Luke", "Ryan"),
"food" = c("pizza", tacos", "sushi", "cake", "brownies", "burgers")

)

name$table_b = as.factor(name$table_b)

table_c <- data.frame (

"name" = c("Johnatha", "Alexande1", "Toma1", "Kevi1", "Luk1"),
"food" = c("pizza", tacos", "sushi", "cake", "brownies")

)

name$table_c = as.factor(name$table_c)
```

Now what I want to do, is run a "left join" if the name in table_a is contained somewhere within the name in table_b. (using the same logic, it should also be possible to use the one-sided %LIKE as well?)

```
#Left joins

join_1 =  merge(x = table_a, y = table_b, by = "%name%", all.x = TRUE)

join_2 =  merge(x = table_b, y = table_c, by = "%name", all.x = TRUE)
```

In regular SQL statements, it is generally straightforward to select rows of data if they meet a condition specified by %LIKE%. Is the same thing possible in R?

```
# select using %LIKE% (is there a way to override "case sensitivity" ? e.g. %like% "jOn"?)

selected_1 = table_a[name %like% "Jon"|| "Ale" || "Pet"]
selected_2 = table_a[name %like% "Jon"|| "Ale" || "Pet" || color %like% "ye"]
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you have two questions here, one about merging data and one about selecting data. For the latter, "data.table" has `%like%` but to access case sensitivity, you have to use the `like()` version. For example, you can do `library(data.table); as.data.table(table_b)[like(name, "joh|al|tom", ignore.case = TRUE) & like(food, "pizza")]`.

Comment: is there a way to do this for a full match? e..g NEW = (table_b) [ (name = "john|tom|alex") $ (food = "pizza)]

Comment: Can you please spend some time making sure the code you give us actually works? Examples: `name$table_a` should be `table_a$name`; and `tacos"` should be `"tacos"`. (I believe.) It can be distracting parsing through typos like that in a question, and wondering what of your problems are due to other typos like that in your real (not-visible) code and how much is related to something else.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will probably need to use other R functions to achieve something which is not done natively with `merge`. `grepl` is the main function that checks if one string is found in another. If you want other patterns you can use `startsWith` (`LIKE%`) or `endsWith` (`%LIKE`), instead of `grepl`.

```
#sapply iterates over the names of table_a
table_a$name_b <- sapply(table_a$name, function(x)  {
                          #check to see if the names of table_a 
                          #are included within table_b
                          #which(...)[1] selects the first instance
                          check <- which(grepl(x, table_b$name, ignore.case = TRUE))[1]
                          #filter table_b and return what matched.
                          table_b$name[check]
                        })
```

Output:

```
# table_a
#   name  color    name_b
#1  John    red Johnathan
#2  Alex   blue Alexander
#3   Tom  green     Tomas
#4   Kev yellow     Kevin
#5 Peter   pink     <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I guess there is no straight forward way to do this .... is there a way to add the "food" column from table_b to your answer?

Comment: Of course! Instead of `table_b$name[check]`, you just add column food, i.e. `table_b$food[check].

Answer (score 3):

You can get fairly close with `fuzzyjoin`:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_right_join(table_b, table_a, by = "name", ignore_case = TRUE)
# Warning: Coercing `pattern` to a plain character vector.
#      name.x  food name.y  color
# 1 Johnathan pizza   John    red
# 2 Alexander tacos   ALex   blue
# 3     Tomas sushi    ToM  green
# 4     Kevin  cake    Kev yellow
# 5      <NA>  <NA>  Peter   pink
```

The `fuzzyjoin` package will rename the `by=` variables here, for the sake of unambiguity. While this might seem inconvenient, I personally find its lack of ambiguity very safe to use. Especially here, where the two will often not be the same (since one is, by definition of our intent, a "pattern" to test against the other).

BTW: `[name %like% "Jon"|| "Ale" || "Pet"]` is not going to do what you hope: it is first producing a `logical` vector based on `name %like% "Jon"`, and then OR-ing that vector as one whole element against `"Ale"` (which is an error), etc. What you might be looking for is a regex-based `%in%`, which is not quite that. Further, `||` is single-element OR, `|` is a vectorized OR, I suspect you want the latter.

For a regex-like `%in%`, you'd want something like:

```r
sapply(c("Jon", "Ale", "Pet"), grepl, x = table_a$name)
#        Jon   Ale   Pet
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

table_a[rowSums(sapply(c("Jon", "Ale", "Pet"), grepl, x = table_a$name)) > 0,]
#    name color
# 5 Peter  pink
table_a[rowSums(sapply(c("Jon", "Ale", "Pet"), grepl, x = table_a$name)) > 0 |
          grepl("ye", table_a$color),]
#    name  color
# 4   Kev yellow
# 5 Peter   pink
```

Which can be turned into a small inline operator like this:

```r
`%regexin%` <- function(lhs, rhs) rowSums(sapply(rhs, grepl, x = as.character(lhs))) > 0
`%iregexin%` <- function(lhs, rhs) rowSums(sapply(rhs, grepl, x = as.character(lhs), ignore.case = TRUE)) > 0

table_a$name %regexin% c("Jon", "Ale", "Pet")
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
subset(table_a, name %regexin% c("Jon", "Ale", "Pet"))
#    name color
# 5 Peter  pink
```

This doesn't help with your join, mind you, though it might be part of some related logic.

---

Data:

```r
table_a <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("ALex", "John", "Kev", "Peter", "ToM"), class = "factor"), color = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
table_b <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Alexander", "Johnathan", "Kevin", "Luke", "Ryan", "Tomas"), class = "factor"), food = c("pizza", "tacos", "sushi", "cake", "brownies", "burgers")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
table_c <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Alexande1", "Johnatha", "Kevi1", "Luk1", "Toma1"), class = "factor"), food = c("pizza", "tacos", "sushi", "cake", "brownies")), row.names = c(NA, -5L ), class = "data.frame")
```